# Rebus stops fetching messages from azure service bus. From 100 messages only 5 I could fetched

Tags: azureservicebus, rebus

I am very newbie at rebus.

I have built the pub/sub example from scratch. Now I am receiving messages in my subscriber.

The problem that I am facing is I publish 100 messages and then suddenly when I start the subscriber service it only gets 5 of those 100 messages.

The windows service does the async task 5 times and then goes out. Am I doing anything wrong?

My subscriber configuration looks like this:

```
using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator()) { 
    activator.Register(() => new TestMessageHandler()); 

    Configure.With(activator) 
        .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(Constants.connectionString, Constants.subQueue)) 
        .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<TestMessage>(Constants.pubQueue)‌​) 
        .Start();

    activator.Bus.Subscribe<TestMessage>().Wait(120000); 
}
```

and my handler looks like this:

```
public async Task Handle(TestMessage message) { 
    var message = string.Format("name: {1} and source name {2} {0} using the warp as a transport {0}", Environment.NewLine, message.Name , message.SourceName);

    await Task.Run(() => Logger(message));
}

private void Logger(TestMessage message) {
    Console.WriteLine(message.ToString(false));
}
```

From the code I posted, is there something that I did wrong?

Comment: Can you try and show the code in your subscriber?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply. Here is my code.

Comment: using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
            {
                activator.Register(() => new  TestMessageHandler());

                Configure.With(activator)                    
                    .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(Constants.connectionString, Constants.subQueue))
                    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<TestMessage>(Constants.pubQueue))
                    .Start();

                activator.Bus.Subscribe<TestMessage>().Wait(120000);
         

            }

Comment: And the handler.

Comment: public async Task Handle(TestMessage message)
        {          
          name: {1} and source name {2} {0} using the warp as a transport {0}", Environment.NewLine, message.Name , message.SourceName);         
            await Task.Run(() => Logger(message));
        }
        private void  Logger(TestMessage message)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(message.ToString(false));
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

From the code

```
using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator()) { 
    (...)
    activator.Bus.Subscribe<TestMessage>().Wait(120000); 
}
```

it seems like your subscriber will almost immediately dispose the `activator` and thus stop the bus.

This hypothesis fits nicely with the behaviour you are experiencing where only the first few messages in the queue are processed.

You should keep the activator instance (or the returned `IBus` if you prefer) around as a singleton for the entire duration of time in which your application is running, and then dispose it when it shuts down.

Comment: Thanks, @mookid, but I thought the wait will be waiting until the queued is empty.... isn't?

Comment: No, that's not how it works... Rebus is meant to be started and kept around for the entire time your application is running, and it will process messages as long as it is running. It is also designed such that it is perfectly OK to stop it anytime, even though many more messages are residing in the queue, if e.g. you want to update your system or whatever... just to resume the message processing when you start it up again